# React router not rendering routes

Tags: reactjs, react-router

Trying to use React Router and I keep getting an error that my Route must be inside a Router, even though it  already is. I've already tried running npm install again, and removing and readding the react router npm package. The error message is

`Invariant failed: You should not use <Route> outside a <Router>`

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import reportWebVitals from './reportWebVitals';
import { BrowserRouter as Router } from 'react-router-dom';

ReactDOM.render(
  <Router>
  <React.StrictMode>
    <App />
  </React.StrictMode>
  </Router>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

app.js

```
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
import Main from './Components/Main/main';
import {BrowserRouter, Route,Link } from 'react-router-dom';

function App() {
  return (

    <div className="App">
      
     
      <Route  exact path='/'>
        <Main />
      </Route>
     
 
    </div>
    
  );
}

export default App;
```

main.js

```
export default function Main(props) {
    const [anim,setAnim] = useState(false);

    return (
        
        <MainSection>
          
        
              
        </MainSection>
     
    )
}
```

Comment: Should work, I tried on my PC and it is working. Maybe put Router inside <React.StrictMode> ?

Comment: Can you create a sandbox to reproduce this error?